# How to disable the property of password-generator in OpenDJ

Tags: ldap, opendj

By default, the value of `password-generator` in `Default Password Policy` is `Random Password Generator`, and then if I try to set a password for a user, I'll get an error shows I cannot provide a password.

But in my case, I want the user can set his/her initial password when the account is created. So, how can I disable the property and just let user set the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password-generator is only used when trying to set or change a password with ldappasswordmodify and no new password is passed as parameter.

If you are getting an error when trying to set a password for a user, it is not due to the password-generator. It's something else, and the error message that you can find in the Access log should be pretty explicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind reply. Actually, the problem is due to default value of `allow-pre-encoded-passwords` is false, and after it has been set to true, I can provide my own password. Thanks again!